# Should I configure BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins on the STM32?

Tags: stm32

On the [STM32F469NI](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00127514-stm32f469xx-and-stm32f479xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) chip there are two pins as BOOT0 and BOOT1. I want to use these pins to boot my chip, so should I configure these pins or is default conditions (reset state) enough to boot chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip has no internal default state so you must connect the default state externally to boot into any mode you want.

You can't leave the pins unconnected and expect the MCU to boot succesfully into whatever mode you want with floating boot config pins.

Comment: So, as I understand that I must change the BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins as GPIO_Input. Am I correct?

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. First of all, BOOT0 is a dedicated pin so it is not a GPIO pin. And the pins are sampled when chip comes out of reset so your code can't possibly have any effect to which mode the chip boots into. Read the datasheet how they work.

Comment: I got the point. Thanks

Comment: @Justme, What about Boot1? The datasheet has said it could be used as GPIO, but when I use it as input it doesn't work.

Comment: @electro I don't know what you are doing that it works, but if you have a new question, please ask a new question. When MCU is already running your program, you can do anything to that pin as it is a GPIO pin.